# Stop empty values from input boxes from being inserted into my database? PHP

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, registration

This is the html form (register.php):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="handle_registration.php" method="post">

<fieldset><legend>Enter your
information in the form below:</legend>

First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" size="20" maxlength="40"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" size="20" maxlength="40"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" size="20" maxlength="40"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pword" size="20" maxlength="40"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit my info">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the php script that handles the registration (handle_registration.php):

```
<?php

// Create a shorthand for the form data:

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pword = $_POST['pword'];

// Create the connection variables:

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "registration_info";
$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass", "$db_name");

// Check the connection:

if (mysqli_connect_errno ())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Make sure all of the input boxes have a value:

if (empty($fname)) {
die('You forgot to enter your first name!');
}

if (empty($lname)) {
die('You forgot to enter your last name!');
}

if (empty($uname)) {
die('You forgot to choose a username!');
}

if (empty($pword)) {
die('You forgot to choose a password!');
}

// Insert the data from the form into the DB:

$sql = "INSERT INTO basic_information (First_Name, Last_Name, Username, Password)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[uname]', '$_POST[pword]')";

// Enter the info the end user type if everything is ok:

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else
{
echo "Record has been added";
}

// Close the connection:

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Here's the problem:

I want to submit the entered values into my database if all of the input fields have a value, but when I use the die function after checking to see if they're empty, then it kills the script. I just want to kill the part were it inserts it into my database if one or more of the fields are empty & display an error message that tells which field was empty. I'm not sure how to get around this and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: refer this url: http://www.w3schools.in/php-tutorial/form-validation/

Comment: 1. Store all errors in an array. if array is empty insert into database else print the array contents.

Comment: You will probably get a few comments, telling you to watch out for SQL-injection and security. That is one issue you should also be looking at. Another one is, whether it might be a better idea to check the form fields right where they originated from, i.e. by some JavaScript/jQuery validator in your client's browser. This way you can give the user a faster response in case of an error (or missing values) and you keep unnecessary traffic from your server.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is rather simple. Just store the error message in a variable and before inserting rows into the DB - check weather the error is set or if it's empty. If it's empty - we can insert the row. Otherwise - let's show the error message.

```
// Currently we do not have an error
$error = NULL;

// Validate
if (empty($pword)) {
    $error = 'You forgot to choose a password!';
}

// If there are no errors - lets insert
if (!$error) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DOn't use die ,use some variable to store errors and print them later

```
 <?php

 // Create a shorthand for the form data:

 $fname = $_POST['fname']; $lname = $_POST['lname']; $uname =
$_POST['uname']; $pword = $_POST['pword'];

// Create the connection variables:

 $db_host = "localhost"; $db_user = "root"; $db_pass = ""; $db_name =
 "registration_info"; $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_user",
 "$db_pass", "$db_name");

 // Check the connection:

 if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .
 mysqli_connect_error(); }

 // Make sure all of the input boxes have a value:

 if (empty($fname)) { $error_msg[]='You forgot to enter your first name!'; }

 if (empty($lname)) { $error_msg[]='You forgot to enter your last name!'; }

 if (empty($uname)) { $error_msg[]='You forgot to choose a username!'; }

 if (empty($pword)) { $error_msg[]='You forgot to choose a password!'; }

 // Insert the data from the form into the DB:
 if(count($error_msg)==0){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO basic_information (First_Name, Last_Name,
 Username, Password) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]',
 '$_POST[uname]', '$_POST[pword]')";

 // Enter the info the end user type if everything is ok:

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); }
 else { echo "Record has been added"; }

 // Close the connection:

 mysqli_close($con);
}else{
print_r($error_msg);
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Full working example to stop insertion of empty data

```
<?php
          if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
              $emptyInput = NULL;
              if (!($_POST["firstname"] == $emptyInput or $_POST["lastname"] == $emptyInput or $_POST["email"] == $emptyInput)) {
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('" . $_POST["firstname"] . "','" . $_POST["lastname"] . "','" . $_POST["email"] . "')";
                  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                      echo 'Record inserted successfully!';
                  }
              } else {
                  echo 'all fields are compulsory!';
              }
          }
          ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a $errors variable to hold the errors with all the fields

```
$error = array();//initializing the $error
if (empty($fname)) {
$error[] = 'You forgot to enter your first name!';
}

if (empty($lname)) {
$error[] = 'You forgot to enter your last name!';
}

if (empty($uname)) {
$error[] = 'You forgot to choose a username!';
}

if (empty($pword)) {
$error[] = 'You forgot to choose a password!';
}

if(!empty($error))//if error occured
{
   die(implode('<br />', $error));//Stops the script and prints the errors if any occured
}
// Insert the data from the form into the DB:

$sql = "INSERT INTO basic_information (First_Name, Last_Name, Username, Password)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[uname]', '$_POST[pword]')";

// Enter the info the end user type if everything is ok:

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else
{
echo "Record has been added";
}

// Close the connection:

mysqli_close($con);
```